# What is a fallback interface and what is it used for?

Tags: networking

When talking about networking what is a fallback interface? and what is it used for?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781550/what-is-a-fallback-interface-and-what-is-it-used-for

Answer (score 1):

do you mean "failback"?  If I understand you correctly, you may have a configuration where you have two or more NIC's setup in an active/passive state.  So let's say you have a group of NICS, 1 and 2.  Number one is active and number 2 is the passive one.  In the event that NIC 1 fails, it will "failover" to NIC 2.  When NIC one comes up as active again your connections will "failback" to NIC one.  This is how VMware networking works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 NICs connected to a network they can be configured in various states, and one of these possible states is in Active/Standby. When that is the case, the Standby link will be brought up on the same address (and sometimes the same MAC address) as the Active NIC in case of a failure on that NIC or it's connection to it's switch. The choice of which one is which is usually made by the server admin at the time of configuration.

This configuration exists to provide high availability on the network connection to the device.